# Listener does not update

Tags: ros, opencv, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon friends

I can get an image of the camera from the gazebo: /camera/image_raw. But if you change the qr code, the listener does not update.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import rospy
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv
import zbar

from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

bridge = CvBridge()

def callback(msg):
    cv2_img = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
    scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
    scanner.parse_config('enable')
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, dstCn=0)

        frame = np.array(gray)
        width, height = frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]

        raw = frame.tostring()

        image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)
        scanner.scan(image)

        qrc = None

        for symbol in image:
            qrc = symbol.data

        if qrc != None:
            qr_str = qrc
            rospy.loginfo(qr_str)

def qr_main():
    rospy.init_node('qr_listener')

    rospy.Subscriber("/camera/image_raw", Image, callback)

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qr_main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259327/listener-does-not-update/) by [icarold](https://answers.ros.org/users/29969/icarold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that your callback does not terminate. This function is called whenever new data arrives. You however, have in infinite loop within your callback so that you look for the qr-code in the first image over an over again.
You somehow assume that your cv2_img-variable gets somehow updated. Wouldn't it be extremely inconvenient if one of your variable changes suddenly why you process it?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [icarold](https://answers.ros.org/users/29969/icarold/) on 2017-04-15**:
Great, my friend!! The problem was the loop!!! Thanks alot for the help!!